# LUKS Container lost due to partitioning by Windows?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, luks, gpt, cryptsetup

I plugged a HDD with a LUKS container on it into Windows and opened the Disk Manager. A dialog appeared where I clicked "Format as GPT", not knowing what I was doing. Apparently Windows wasn't able to read the existing LUKS partition and just overwrote it.

Now cryptsetup doesn't recognize the container anymore and my HDD looks like this:

`fdisk -l /dev/sda`

> Disk /dev/sda: 3,64 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors 
> Disk model: ST4000DM004-2CV1
> Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
> I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
> Disklabel type: gpt
> Disk identifier: A149A5A1-E9D1-4DA3-AE90-8EFD1DB81F44
>
> Device     Start   End Sectors Size Type
> /dev/sda1     34 32767 32734  16M   Microsoft reserved
>
> **Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.**

Is there ANY WAY to restore the container again, or do I have to say goodbye to my data?

Comment: The painful lesson that goads many to start proper backups.

Comment: If you have lost important data you might be able to recover some using the testdisk app.